# Как сделать градиент поверх картинки?

Tags: css, веб-дизайн

Должна быть картинка, градиент, и текст поверх всего этого. Никак не получается сделать, пробую разные приемы, ничего не срабатывает.

```
.header {
    height: 670px;

    width: 100%;

    background-image: url(../img/header_bg.png);

    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(9, 5, 47, .85) 0%, rgba(49, 29, 94, .85) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`linear-gradient` - это  изображение, поэтому изображения (фон и градиент) надо прописывать через запятую

```
.header {
    height: 670px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(9, 5, 47, .85) 0%, rgba(49, 29, 94, .85) 100%), url(../img/header_bg.png);
}
```

Далее, если я правильно понял про вопрос суть с текстом, то:

Создаете блок и присваиваете ему такой класс, заполняя текстом, пример:

```
<div class="header">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris enim enim, semper sed libero placerat, venenatis eleifend velit. Aliquam imperdiet nunc in libero condimentum viverra. Quisque eu est et mauris pellentesque vulputate. Curabitur posuere sollicitudin urna id malesuada. Vivamus tincidunt tristique diam, id porttitor neque tempor at. Quisque eget enim in tortor scelerisque vehicula vel eget justo. Nunc rutrum iaculis tortor at porttitor.
</div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Legionary/o9fpzgjm/).

Comment: написал градиент после картинки, но он не отображается. Он за картинкой

Comment: @PolonskiyP нужно изменить порядок, сначала градиент, потом картинка. Поправил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Comment: Красавчик...Реально выручил. Искал везде, четкого ответа не было.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютами:

```css
.header {
    height: 670px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Blue_Tiger_Im_IMG_9450.jpg) center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(9, 5, 47, .85) 0%, rgba(49, 29, 94, .85) 100%);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: center;
}

.text p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div  class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, eos?</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

P.S: Ваш пример не работает из-за конфликта фонов.

Comment: на самом деле у меня была сначала картинка, а потом градиент. Поменял местами и все сработало.